# SSIS package won't execute in visual basic anymore - instead goes through a "build"

Tags: ssis

I'm a super beginner using Visual Studio 2017 to create my first SSIS package. This package opens a flat file (.csv) and adds it to a table on the SQL server. When I press the Start button (in Visual Studio), the SSIS package used to execute perfectly. Something changed, so now when I press start, the package doesn't execute, but instead, performs a "Build" and outputs:

```
------ Build started: Project: LabData, Configuration: Development ------
Build started: SQL Server Integration Services project: Incremental ...
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm that when you click the down arrow on the Start button, there are no other options other than Start. If this still runs a build, go to the ribbon on the top, click Debug, and click Start with/without Debugging. That should execute the package normally.

There should also be two boxes to the left of the Start button. Confirm that those have not been changed or that you didn't make changes in the config manager. You can get to the config manager by clicking one of those boxes and selecting Configuration Manager.

Comment: When clicking the down arrow on the Start button, the only option is Start. When I click Debug->Start with/without debugging, it still goes through the build routine. The two boxes to the left of the Start button are set to "Development" and "Default" respectively. In configuration Manager, the "Build" box is checked.

Comment: @FinnB Open the solution explorer under View in the ribbon, navigate to your package, right click it, and click Execute package.

Comment: Opened solution explorer, navigated to package - only the default "Package,dtsx" was there, not the package I was working on. So I right clicked on SSIS Packages (in solution explorer)->Add existing packages, and entered the package path. It works. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @FinnB. Stupid Visual Studio once again dropped my package from the solution. The difference in me adding it was getting the error that the package was already there.